# What theological problems could arise from the discovery of human like extraterrestrials and sapient non human extraterrestrials

Tags: society, religion, interspecies-relations

I am working on a science fiction setting (near future and about ninety years after first contact with an alien civilization and the discovery of a bustling galactic community) and I'm wanting to portray a diverse set of beliefs and philosophies from our world in my setting due to it not being based on our world. I saw a similar question asked specifically about Christianity but wanted to know how this shook out for the other major religions

So, what theological problems could arise from the discovery of human like extraterrestrials and sapient non humans? Could this cause doctrinal shift in how the soul is perceived? How could this effect the ideas of reincarnation? I'm sure there's more facets but I am woefully uninformed and want to expand my understanding so I can do justice to the various faiths of the world and make the 2270s feel more lived in and true to life.

Comment: (1) Welcome to WorldBuilding! I hope that you will enjoy partipating on this site. You may want to take the [tour] and peruse the [help] in order to become better acquainted with the rules and expectations of this site. (2) This is a very interesting research program; I would certainly like very much to read a book exploring the philosophical and ideological impact of estabilishing contact with a variety of extraterrestrial civilizations. (3) This is a *vast* research program. Way beyond the limited scope of a short answer. (cont.)

Comment: (Cont.) (4) Be aware that most people of this world don't give a toss about theological problems. Most people in Europe, or in China, for example, are utterly uninterested in theology. (5) When you say a "doctrinal shift in how the soul is perceived" you imply that there is a universal baseline. There is no such thing -- various religions and philosophical schools have different understandings, and, moreover, materialist schools of thought have no concept of a "soul" at all. (6) Reincarnation is a doctrine of certain exotic far-eastern religions. (7) "Affect" and "effect" are different words.

Comment: VTC:Needs More Focus. (a) this is an off-topic [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868). (b) The [help/on-topic] states, "If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question." (c) The [help/dont-ask] states, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “'What if ______ happened?'”

Comment: To build on what @AlexP explained, (1) There are nine billion people on this planet and who knows how many political/educational/social/philisophical/etc organizations - and they're all capable of acting differently. Do you want to know how my little sister would react? No? How about just New Yorkers, or just the people on Madagascar? Or just U.S. Republicans? I hope you see my point - no focus. (2) From the [help/on-topic], "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story." This is literally asking us to write your story.

Comment: Finally, (3) the [help/dont-ask] states, "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." Considering (1) entire libraries could be written to answer your question - and every page in those libraries would be correct. From the [Help Center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) "If your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format."

Comment: This really should be limited to one religion.  OTOH, I note that from Europe's point of view, we've already faced it.  We would say that human-like extraterrestrials are not human because they do not come from a common origin from us.  After Columbus, many intellectuals pondered whether these really human-like beings could have a common origin.  The Pope issued a bull redefining human to mean a being capable of becoming a Christian to cope.

Answer (score 4):

No theological problems would be inevitable.

Many theological problems would be possible.

In case you have not noticed, there are tens and hundreds - at least - of Christian sects and denominations around the world.  Almost every sect,denominatin, or other group has a theology which differs in at least one detail from the theologies of other groups.

You might remember from history that there have been many persections of Christians by Christians, and religious wars between Christian groups, in history.  So clearly many Christians have considered, and some still consider, theological differences between various Christian groups to be deadly serious.

So it is quite possible that many Christian groups would have no problems with the postulaed discoveries, while some groups might have such big problems with those discoveries that they would seek to exterminate those beings and censor all record of their having existed, to ensure that nobody in the future will know about them. And members of other groups might have theological problems which are not strong enough to drive them to genocide, but which are still significant.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little tongue in cheek, but it does present (in essence) a class of issue which just might arise that would cause a theological tsunami.

Imagine an alien ambassador happens to land in Italy and the locals take him to see the Pope. The Pope is keen to to ask the ambassador some questions. "Do you believe in God and have you heard of Christ?" says the Pope.

Ambassador: "You mean Jesus Christ?, Oh yes we know Jesus"

Pope (in excited tone): "Really! how long ago did he visit you?"

Ambassador: "He comes every year"

Pope (in astonishment): "What! *every* year?!"

Ambassador: "Yes, once every year. How often does he visit you?"

Pope: "Well... he's only been here once and that was around 2000 years ago"

Ambassador: "hmmmm, perhaps he doesn't like your cookies..."

Pope (shocked): "Pardon!"

Ambassador: "When Jesus come to visit us there's always a big celebration. He cures a few of the blind and lame and he gives us all sorts of advice on how to run the government and act justly and fairly. In return we put him up in a five star holiday resort complex and lay on special entertainment and celebrations - a bit of a working holiday for him. And when he leaves by tradition we always give him a big box of chocolate cookies. He loves chocolate cookies you know"

Pope (dumfounded and somewhat aghast): "Ahh err...."

Ambassador: "What did you do for him when he came to see you?"

Answer (score 0):

## You can't predict this

The evolution of religions, including Christianity, offers a great deal of variety.  Think of the Puritans, who would denounce the wearing of a crucifix or playing music in church as idolatry; then compare a *700 Club* broadcast that advertises an eagle statue for prayerful contemplation.  You can go down any issue you like this way, and find churches that have been on various sides of an issue or attach very different importance or interpretations to the same words.  This was most often contemporaneously (nowadays very few folks can offer an opinion on homoiousian vs. homoousian, but it was *very* important to people at one time).

It's perfectly reasonable for your story to say that a church is *exactly* the way it was in 2022, or any other year, by deliberate effort; but it is also fine to invent something completely new.  It's your chance to ponder the philosophy and offer what insight you might -- so long as you're honest and thoughtful, you can't be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

## Alien Trolls:

The answer Slarty gave got me thinking: What if the aliens don't LIKE us? Or what if they disapprove of religion? Imagine a group of aliens who are smarter than us, with technology we barely understand, who decide to screw with humans? We don't know their motives. They could create false evidence (or have real evidence, and we couldn't tell the difference) that Christianity was a sham, or Buddha was a pedophile, Allah was an alien or that a god they fabricated was the "true" God.

A campaign against human faiths might sound too grand for a few alien trolls to execute, but extraterrestrials with means at hand that put abilities in single individual's hands that exceed the abilities of the entire human race?

Or what about actual alien religions? What happens when ZZygad's witnesses start showing up on human door steps preaching the good news of the true prophet? They might have "evidence" of their God's truth that a human wouldn't be able to refute, even if a sophisticated extraterrestrial wouldn't be taken in by flimsy "irrefutable" evidence.

And there is always the concern that conversion might be less voluntary than we would like. Besides trade being dependent on what faith you follow, there could be crusades, or mind control, or drugs that cause ecstatic religious experiences. Who can compete with an alien faith that can let you experience God by taking a pill and being profoundly changed afterwards?

And let's not forget genuine miracles. Their preachers can heal the sick, drive out demons (cure mental illness), materialize food out of thin air to feed the hungry, and let's not forget walking on water or seemingly raising the dead.

Answer (score -1):

Some of the big questions in Christianity are whether events in the Bible refer to Humans or to all sentient lifeforms.

For example original sin. Humans were created in a state of grace but lost it and gained original sin due to disobeying God in the Garden of Eden. Later some of this original sin was forgiven by the whole Jesus of Nazarath Debacle.

If there are extraterrestrials then there are several options for their state of grace.

1. They were created outside of grace
2. They were created in grace but lost it due to the Garden of Eden which happened on Earth.
3. They were created in grace but lost it due to their own version of the Garden of Eden which happened on their own home planet.
4. They were created in grace but lost it due to the Garden of Eden which was a much more metaphysically abstract event than a man with a fruit in a garden, and in fact happened all over the universe at once.
5. They were created in grace but never fell in the first place.

Likewise there are several options for whether the aliens have their own Alien messiah or whether there was only one Jesus and he forgave all sapient people simultaneously.

Comment: What is the universal Christian meaning of the phrase "created in grace"? Do all variants of Christianity (or at least all mainstream variants) affirm that humans ever lost God'd grace, because eating unspecified fruit or for any other reason?

Comment: *"It's a religious jargon term":* Citation needed.

Comment: It's unfair that this answer has been downvoted. I'm a Christian and the relationship that Jesus has to the ET's is surely the first question that occurs to any of us; that in turn is inseparable from the question of sin and original sin and how ET's are affected. Lewis's Space Trilogy is centred on option 5 and dwells on fleshing it out for two of the three books. The phrase "a state of grace" is indeed universally understood to refer to the condition of Adam and Eve prior to the fall, although it won't be the preferred term of every denomination.

Comment: Re: "created in grace", it's debatable if it applies to Adam but it is indeed a theological term. See e.g. Aquinas on the topic: https://www.newadvent.org/summa/1095.htm

Comment: My only question is why the life of Jesus is referred to as a debacle?